# Get the first visible item in a ListView whose View property is Tile

Tags: c#, listview

I have defined the following ListView with the View property in Tile mode, since it is assigned a list of images, ImageList1:

```
ListView1.AllowDrop = true;
ListView1.View = View.Tile;
ListView1.FullRowSelect = true;
ListView1.GridLines = true;
ListView1.Columns.Add("indice", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
ListView1.Columns.Add("nombre", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
ListViewCanalesDelFichero.LargeImageList = ImageList1;
```

When I access the ListView.TopItem property  to get the item that visually appears first in the ListView  as follows,

```
string item = ListView1.TopItem.SubItems[1].Text;
```

an exception is thrown:
**"You can't get the top item in the LargeIcon, SmallIcon, or Tile view. "**
The problem is in the View property that is in Tile.  In View.Details mode there is no problem.
What do I have to do to, while maintaining the Tile mode, get the first visible item?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Are you talking about the MS `WPF` UI Framework, or `Windows Forms` or something else?

Comment: It is a real problem, at issue is that "top item" is ambiguous in Tile and Icon modes.  ListView then allows scrolling items smoothly.  Is it still the top item when the bottom row of pixels of a tile is still visible?  What if they are not different from the background?  Make your own by iterating the items, retrieving the Bounds property.  And setting your own rule for how much of an item must be visible to be considered on top.